# how to display specific row from database with angular and php?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

im building a project with angular and php, i can register a new "customer" and display all customers details, but i can't display specific row from the database. can someone please help? thank you

customerCardDetailsCtrl.js - controller for getting specific customer

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').
controller('customerCardDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $http ,$routeParams, $location) {

  var customer_id = $routeParams.customer_id;
  $scope.customer_id = customer_id;
  var data = $.param({
    customer_id: customer_id
});

var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
    }
}


  $http.post('api/readCustomer.php/' +customer_id,data,config ).

  success(function(data){
    $scope.customerDetails = data;

  }).
  error (function (error) {
    colsole.log(error);
  });
});
```

app.js - specific route

```
  .when('/customerCardDetails/:customer_id', {
                controller: "customerCardDetailsCtrl",
                templateUrl: '../hamatkin/Views/customerCardDetails.html',
                screenTitle: "",
                costumerHidden: false,
                reportsHidden: true,
                stockHidden: true,
                isIncome_expensesHidden: true,
                isNavTabHidden: false,
                isFooterHidden: false,
                ordersHidden: true

            })
```

readCustomer.php - php code for getting specific customer

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    include_once 'Customer.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results = utf8");


    $customer = new Customer();


    $query = "SELECT customer_id, kind_Of_Customer, full_name, id, city, address,phone,phone_2 FROM customers where customer_id= 82";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    // reset the result resource
    // mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    if( $result->num_rows!=0)
    {


        $customer->kind_Of_Customer = $row['kind_Of_Customer'];
        $customer->full_name =$row['full_name'];
        $customer->id = $row['id'];
        $customer->city = $row['city'];
        $customer->address = $row['address'];
        $customer->phone = $row['phone'];
        $customer->phone_2 = $row['phone_2'];

    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($customer); die;
    $res = json_encode($customer);
     echo $res;

?>
```

CustomerCardDetails.html - html page for displaying specific customer

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="customerDetail">
    <h1>כרטיס לקוח</h1>
    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCards">חזור לרשימת כרטיסי הלקוחות</a>
    <div class="specific" >
      customer id: {{customerDetails.customer_id}}</br>
       customer full name: {{customerDetails.full_name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an error ? Btw it should be a $http.get instead of $http.post('api/readCustomer.php...

Comment: you hardcoded `customer_id = 82` in your query, and never use the customer id you sent over in the ajax call...

Comment: @oliv37 don't have any errors, the object is getting specific customer details but i don't know how to display...i changed to $http.get but still not showing

Comment: @MarcB how to change "82" to any customer id?

Comment: you should use the query String

Comment: @oliv37 how to use it?